# Are there APIs for translating short url's back to regular links?

Tags: url, twitter, friendly-url, bit.ly, short-url

I want to translate bulk numbers of short url's coming streamed from twitter. Rather than accessing each individual request I want to use API's that accept a list of short or tiny URL's and return the original URL's.  Are such API's available?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902192/how-to-get-long-url-from-short-url

Answer (score 5):

Not really an API, but this will give you the URL really fast.

`curl -I` insert short URL here  `| grep Location | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: This is still very useful in 2024!

Answer (score 4):

99% of all url openers have an API.

For example, there's a PEAR package (PHP) called [Services_ShortURL](http://github.com/joestump/services_shorturl/tree/master) that supports:

- bit.ly
- digg
- is.gd
- short.ie
- tinyurl.com

Answer (score 1):

There are a few web-sites around that are dedicated services to converting shortened URLs back to their original.

Two I know of that have APIs are [LongURL](http://longurl.org/api) and [Untiny.me](http://untiny.me/api/).  I'm in the middle of writing a java library to use both of these.

Answer (score 1):

I had written a small [script](https://github.com/vsr/Tiny2Long/blob/master/index.php) to turn short urls to it's original links. It's based on the http header returned by the short urls.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [bit.ly API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) or [budurl.com API](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/budurl/frames)

Comment: That is the bit.ly API...  How is it going to help with all the other short URL services?

Comment: He specifically asked for APIs'.

Answer (score 0):

From Untiny.me's online service, this was useful: 
`http://untiny.me/api/1.0/extract/?format=text&url=bit.ly/GFscreener12`

So conceivably a simple Bash script reading each line as a short URL would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# urlexpander.sh by MarcosK
 while read URLline; do
  curl -s "untiny.me/api/1.0/extract/?format=text&url=$URLline"
 done
```

To test, feed it a single URL with `echo "bit.ly/GFscreener12" | ./urlexpander.sh`
or send it your whole input file, one short URL per line, with:

```
cat urllist.txt | ./urlexpander.sh
```

Comment: However for my own code I actually like [gahooa's method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134628/1069375) better because it doesn't need to check a 3rd party service nor make an extra web fetch, and most importantly, works equally well with standard URLs not just short--returning them unchanged.  So change the `curl` line inside the while loop to `curl -sI "$URLline" | grep Location | awk '{print $2}'`